# Not getting Django error emails

Tags: django, email, error-handling, postfix-mta, python-2.x

I get this in my maillog when I visit a page with an error.

`connect from localhost[127.0.0.1] NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 504 5.5.2 <P>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address; from=<admin@site.net> to=<P> proto=ESMTP helo=<Web-Mail--Host2.site.net>`

Here is the relevant code from my settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
ADMINS = (
    'Name', 'email@gmail.com',
)


MANAGERS = ADMINS
EMAIL_HOST = "site.net"
SERVER_EMAIL = "admin@site.net"
```

I have done this before by basically just adding my email to the admin list and adding EMAIL_HOST and SERVER_EMAIL, but it's not working on this server.

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` and all the log lines of a mail transaction generated by postfix to help you better.

Comment: Sep  7 21:07:48 server postfix/smtpd[11458]: warning: database /etc/aliases.db is older than source file /etc/aliases
Sep  7 21:07:48 server postfix/smtpd[11458]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  7 21:07:48 server postfix/smtpd[11458]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 504 5.5.2 <P>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address; from=<user@site.tld> to=<P> proto=ESMTP helo=<www.site.tld>

Comment: Sep  7 21:07:49 server postfix/smtpd[11458]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 504 5.5.2 <a>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address; from=<admin@site.tld> to=<a> proto=ESMTP helo=<www.site.tld>
Sep  7 21:07:49 server postfix/smtpd[11458]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eh1t5SY3

Comment: Why are mails sent to `a` and `P`? Your `reject_non_fqdn_recipient` restriction under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is rejecting the mail.also ur alias database is out of date. So please run `postalias /etc/postfix/aliases`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation i noticed I had to add brackets in my admin list.

```
'Name', 'email@gmail.com',
```

was changed to 
    ('Name', 'email@gmail.com'),

and I got the email.